# How to cumulate time durations

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

I am using boost::format variable to get elapsed time in seconds

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration  total_time = start_1.elapsed();
long milliseconds = total_time.total_milliseconds();
boost::format output("%.6f");
output % (milliseconds/1000.0);
```

But I use the timer several times to cumulate durations.
I want to know with which type of variable can I cumulate durations ( use the **operator +**). For example with a float by I don't know how to convert **from boost::format to float**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_operators), `time_duration` has `operator +`. So it is possible to use `time_duration` itself to accumulate durations.